# Parameter Error in Python - Text Adventure Game

Tags: python, class, import, init

Trying to make a text adventure with a game engine somewhat in Python. Anyway I keep getting this error message. `TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Here is my code:

```
from engine import game
from engine import event
from engine import place


class TextAdventureGame(game):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TextAdventureGame, self).__init__()
        self.introduction = ('''Welcome to Can You Escape text adventure game.
You wake up in a dark room and you have no idea where you are.''')
```

Why does this error occur?

`class TextAdventureGame(game):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: how are you instantiating your class?

Comment: Consider changing the title of the question to something that reflects your concrete problem.

Comment: 1: is that your entire code? 2: if you remove `super(TextAdventureGame, self).__init__()`, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

This question is posed in a way that is very difficult to answer, but from the looks of it, I would say that the error is here:

```
class TextAdventureGame(game):
```

It's saying `module.__init__()`, not `TextAdventureGame.__init__()`, which makes me think that `game` is a module that is getting used in an odd way.  But without knowing any else about your code, what `game` is, or seeing a stack trace, we can't really do much more.

Answer (score 1):

`game` is a module. You should use a class as a base class instead.

```
>>> import os
>>> class C(os):
...   pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```